# Socket.io not working without JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, socket.io, socket.io-1.0

I've been trying out socket.io and have obviously started with their chat app. The client-side code on their side looks somthing like this:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Socket.IO chat</title>
    <style>
      * { margin: 0; padding: 0; box-sizing: border-box; }
      body { font: 13px Helvetica, Arial; }
      form { background: #000; padding: 3px; position: fixed; bottom: 0; width: 100%; }
      form input { border: 0; padding: 10px; width: 90%; margin-right: .5%; }
      form button { width: 9%; background: rgb(130, 224, 255); border: none; padding: 10px; }
      #messages { list-style-type: none; margin: 0; padding: 0;}
      #messages li { padding: 5px 10px; }
      #messages li:nth-child(odd) { background: #eee; }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <ul id="messages"></ul>
    <form action="" id = "frm">
      <input id="m" autocomplete="off" /><button id='b'>Send</button>
    </form>
    <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
    <script>
      var socket = io();
      $('form').submit(function(){
        socket.emit('chat message', $('#m').val());
        $('#m').val('');
        return false;
      });
      socket.on('chat message', function(msg){
        $('#messages').append($('<li>').text(msg));
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Now, my problem is that if I try to change the code inside the callback function inside the socket.on block with something like:

```
document.getElementById('messages').innerHTML += '<li>' + msg + '</li>';
```

the li element appears, for like half a second, and then the innerHTML resets, the same thing happens if I try editing any other part of the DOM inside the callback ?

I don't use Jquery but common sense made me assume

```
$('#messages').append($('<li>').text(msg))
```

; is basically equivalent with modifying the innerHTML in the way I wrote above. What am I doing wrong ? Is socket.io made in such a way that it can only use Jquery inside its call backs ? (I tried this in serveral browser).

Comment: The answer to this : "Is socket.io made in such a way that it can only use Jquery inside its call backs ?" Is no.  Your issue has nothing to do with Socket.io

Answer (score 0):

The two codes perform equally in JSFiddle, so I can't tell why one works within socket.io and one doesn't, but in looking up related questions, I've seen a few answers suggesting not to use `+=` with `document.innerHTML`.  I haven't found a reason why this poses any problems beyond the [minor security concern](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML#Security_considerations), but they suggest using [`appendChild()`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_node_appendchild.asp) instead.